# Rendering image on the mobile browser?

Tags: asp.net, image, opera, mobile-controls

i am creating a mobile site, now my problem is the images are getting render when i run the site on PC, and also while running the site on IPhone, but when it comes to Opera Browser for any symbian based mobile, the images are not at all rendering..

i am using asp:Image control on the site.. is this causing it not to be displayed on mobile.
if yes, then whats the equivalent for the mobile control. and also i want to resize the image as per the aspect ratio almost all the images are big in dimension.

Please anyone have any idea for the same, i will appreciate it.

Comment: Can you share a link to a development version of the site? It's quite hard to know what precisely is going on...

Comment: @abbas any progress on this. Could you answer your own question if you found a solution. That would help to have it filtered out of non-answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to have your pages and images resize automatically based on the size of the device on which they are being viewed, you might find an answer with Zurb Foundation.  I use it in almost all of my web "responsive web design" projects now.

http://foundation.zurb.com/